# Can a iOS user join a world with a PC user?

Tags: terraria

I can't figure out if the PC version user can join an iOS version's user world. I tried connecting, but I don't know if I have to click `Join Via Steam` or `Join Via IP`.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't.

Despite being the same game, they are two different versions; even with the exact same content, the PC and mobile versions of Terraria work differently, and making them interact like you would with two mobile games or two PC games is not a simple task. Or not, see comments.

Comment: From the programming side of things, since both have the same content it actually is a pretty simple task to make them work together. It's no harder then doing PC-PC or Phone-phone, especially when you already have PC-PC and Phone-Phone working already. Source: I'm a programmer who has multilayer and networking experience

Comment: @KeithM Networking does work the same in both iOS and the PC indeed. I also think that you can get the Terraria server source, but the difficulty is questionable, as there could be a need of modifying the game clients.

Answer (score 0):

As it is, you cannot do it. The PC version and the mobile version are different in terms of items, bosses, etc.

It *might* be possible to make some sort of "crossover" server, but I bet that it would require effort, and you would need to make a Terraria mod on the PC, or a modified game client for compatibility with the server. I am not sure if the source for iOS is available, but the PC server source is AFAIK.